# What size fasteners should I use to mount fence bases to concrete?

Tags: concrete, screws, fence, anchor

We're anchoring several 4" x6" x 1/4" steel plates to concrete. They will be used for a fence. These bases need to be solid, but it's simply to separate one area from another (people won't be near it).

Initially, we were going to use these [3/8" x 3" anchor screws](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Simpson-Strong-Tie-3-8-in-x-3-in-Titen-Heavy-Duty-Screw-Anchor-50-per-Pack-THD37300H/205225113), but someone here mentioned `expansion type anchors`. I started searching to see what this is, and found several images: [Image1](http://www.engineersjournal.ie/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/New-Picture33.png), [image2](https://ars.els-cdn.com/content/image/1-s2.0-S0029549315001089-gr1.jpg), [image3](https://sc01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1oiuNGFXXXXbRXVXXq6xXFXXX6/221206607/HTB1oiuNGFXXXXbRXVXXq6xXFXXX6.jpg).

Are these anchors stronger than the 3/8" x 3" anchor screws? Can these anchors be removed in the future?

Comment: The stress on a fence isn't normally from human activity. It's from the massive amount of cumulative force the wind can create. That, coupled with the torque multiplication those small bases create, means that you could have hundreds of pounds of pullout force being applied.

Answer (score 1):

A steel plate like you describe will presumably have some type of post or support attached to it. That attachment will be able to place a whole bunch of torque on the plate and the last thing you want is for the plate to start pulling loose when some chincey and cheap anchor screw starts to pull out of the concrete.

I would recommend the larger size if you are indeed going to be using the direct screw in type of concrete anchor. Be aware that the screw in concrete anchor does require an accurate hole diameter and deeper penetration into the concrete and larger diameter lead to better holding power. Follow instructions carefully on how this type of anchor is installed.

If you have a situation where:

1. You have a hard time drilling holes into concrete and keeping the hole diameter from getting enlarged too much.
2. You do not need to be close to the edge of the concrete.

...then you may want to consider some quality expansion type anchors instead. Good ones will set you back cost wise even more than the larger screw in anchors that you linked to.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a link to the "expansion type anchors"? I don't know what they are.

Comment: One manufacturer with good info:  http://www.powers.com/mechanical.php